# i want to make bill against given order no and then i want to show delivered qty and then balance

Tags: oracle, function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "DELIVERED_QTY" (ordno IN VARCHAR2, itemid IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN NUMBER
IS
   V  NUMBER (5);
BEGIN
   SELECT SUM (Qty)
     INTO V
     FROM BILLC c, BILLM m
    WHERE     c.BILL_NO_FK = m.BILL_NO
          AND m.ORDER_NO = ORDNO
          AND c.Item_id = ITEMID.

   RETURN V;
END;
```

can anyone explain we this function why we take 2 arguments in this ordno and itemid?

Answer (score 0):

Code you posted is invalid, that procedure won't even compile (and certainly can't return any result). Statement should be terminated with a semi-colon, not a dot (the last condition in `where` clause).

Apart from that: why does it take two arguments? Because

- `order_no` belongs to `billm` table, and
- `item_id` belongs to `billc` table

so - as you're joining them, you need to match column values from both tables to two arguments you passed.

Function, therefore, returns quantity **per item** for that particular order.

---

If you - as the title suggests - want to calculate total quantity **per order**, then you wouldn't need the `itemid` argument:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "DELIVERED_QTY" (ordno IN VARCHAR2)
   RETURN NUMBER
IS
   V  NUMBER (5);
BEGIN
   SELECT SUM (Qty)
     INTO V
     FROM BILLC c, BILLM m
    WHERE     c.BILL_NO_FK = m.BILL_NO
          AND m.ORDER_NO = ORDNO;

   RETURN V;
END;
```